# Laravel: Get all projects and check if user has liked them

Tags: laravel

I want to get all projects, and foreach project I want to get a property for example `is_liked` which indicates that if the current_user (I've his Id) has liked this project or not.

**User Model**

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }

    public function favorite_projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'favorite_projects', 'user_id', 'project_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Project Model**

```
class Project extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

**User Table**

```
- id
- name
```

**Project Table**

```
- id
- user_id
- title
```

**favorite_projects table**

```
- user_id
- project_id
```

What is the best way to get this done ? the data I want to get is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 3,
        "title": "my title",
        "is_liked": true
    }
]
```

**Note**: the current_user->id might or might not be same as the project->user_id.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$projects = DB::table('projects')
               ->join('favorite_projects', 'favorite_projects.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
               ->select('projects.*', 'favorite_projects.*')
               ->where('projects.user_id', Auth::id())
               ->get();
```

This join statement allows you to join 2 tables together and for each project that is being favorited by the user, you will see the favorite record attached with the record.
Perform a `dd($projects)` after that SQL query and see what the result is like, and then for each result, you set `$project['is_liked']` accordingly.

Comment: This query will only give me a list of only favorited projects which is not what I want, I want the list to contains all the projects (favorited or not) and if the project is favorited then add the `is_liked` field to it.

Comment: so with the query above, you can do a `->pluck('id')` to get all favorite project ids, and then for each user project, you can use the `->whereIn()` for collection to check if the project is within the list of favorite project IDs, if yes then you set "is_likes" to true

Comment: This way I have to get all projects separately and store them in array, then loop through all of them and set `is_liked` to true if the project_id is in the favorite_project_ids list. this works fine but I was trying to avoid this for loop if possible.

Comment: You don't need to avoid the loop, you need to avoid loop of database query, since you had already get a list of favorite projects out, then no more DB query is needed, looping through an array is not going to take as much time as doing DB queries